# Installshield - Install prerequisite while uninstalling application

Tags: installshield, prerequisites

I created an application in Installshield 2012 using the BASIC MSI as a project type.

I have four prerequisites in this setup. All is working fine. But in case I uninstall any of the prerequisites from the control panel and then suppose I am going to uninstall the application at that time it gives me a dialog to install that prerequisite. but at the time of uninstalling the application, I don't want to check for prerequisite.

Please Help me to resolve this thing.

Comment: I can't see how this is possible. What happens if you uninstall via the maintenance mode (i.e invoke setup.exe not control panel)?

Answer (score 0):

Was your 2012 project upgraded from previous versions of InstallShield?  It sounds like you have LaunchConditions that don't have "or Installed"  appended to them and they are reevaluating.  New Basic MSI projects have a condition on LaunchConditions in the Install Sequences to prevent them from evaluating during an uninstall but it doesn't sound like this is the case for you.

Comment: No. I didn't upgrade from previous version. I edit the .prq file and tried to change the Launch Condition. But it not allowed me to set the condition like "Not Remove".  Also if I change the Launch Condition for an application then it applicable to the EXE/MSI file but not the Prerequisites..... Am I right..? Please correct me.

Comment: The Launch Conditions I refer to aren't in the PRQ files but are in the ISM file.  InstallShield calls them Install Conditions and they are found in Installation Information | General Information | General | Install Condition.   But if you never upgraded it should be working because InstallShield doesn't call Launch Conditions by default during uninstalls.    Can you post a Windows Installer log file and/or screen shots of your error?

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for reply. It's not error. Its like wrong behavior of the application. I have 4 prereq. for my application. At the time of installation/modify, application check for prereq. and if any of them is not installed then application will install it. But same thing is checked by application while I am uninstall the application which should not be the case.